# Compact Matrix in Latex

Tags: latex, matrix

For a summary I want to display a latex matrix in an as compact as possible way. How can I do that?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the *smallmatrix* environment

```
running text bla 
$\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
a&b\\ c&d
\end{smallmatrix} \bigr)$
continue with text
```

Comment: Instead of using \big and similar commands, consider using \left( and \right) (or \left[ \left{ and so on) because these auto-adjust the parantheses/brackets.